# ASCX controls ASP.NET - Cannot find Visible method

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, methods

In a particular page i have a ascx control which contains a table.

Now I want to set this control visible/invisible but the visible method is not detected by the intellisense.

The only methods are 1)Equals and 2) ReferenceEquals

Main Page

```
<VPM:VotingPolls Runat="server"></VPM:VotingPolls>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks it has been solved

The problem was that no id was set.

```
<VPM:VotingPolls ID="VPS" Runat="server"></VPM:VotingPolls>
```

then

```
VPS.Visible=True/False
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your markup is well formed and that there is a proper header line for the ascx control on your page.  99% of the time, if intellisense doesn't work, it means that something is wrong with the code and/or markup.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes intellisense doesn't display available attributes. But the visible attribute will be available. So just type visible='true/false'. That should work.

Comment: it didn't work..... (Reference to a non-shared member requires an object refernce)